# C++ binary reading to dynamic char

Tags: c++, binary, char, fstream

Something wrong with my code and I don't know what exactly causes the problem.

Source.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

int main()
{
    Book book1("At Mountain of Madness", "H.P Lovecraft", 1936);
    book1.binaryFileWrite();
    book1.binaryFileRead();

    Book book2("Danwych's horror", "H.P Lovecraft", 1929);
    book2.binaryFileWrite();
    book2.binaryFileRead();

    
}
```

```
#ifndef BOOK_BINARY_LIBRARY
#define BOOK_BINARY_LIBRARY

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Book
{
public:
    Book()
        : _year(0)
    {
        _title = new char[10];
        _author = new char[10];
        strcpy(_title, "Undefined");
        strcpy(_author, "Undefined");
    }

    Book(const char *title, const char *author, int year)
        : _year(year)
    {
        _titleLen = strlen(title);
        _authorLen = strlen(author);
        _title = new char[_titleLen + 1];
        _author = new char[_authorLen + 1];
        strcpy(_title, title);
        strcpy(_author, author);
    }

    Book(const Book& book)
    {
        _titleLen = strlen(book._title);
        _authorLen = strlen(book._author);
        _title = new char[_titleLen + 1];
        _author = new char[_authorLen + 1];
        strcpy(_title, book._title);
        strcpy(_author, book._author);
    }

    ~Book()
    {
        delete[] _title;
        delete[] _author;
    }
    void display() 
    {
        std::cout << _title << " " << _author << " " << _year << std::endl;
    }

    void binaryFileWrite(const std::string &fileName = "binaryLibrary.bin")
    {
        std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            /*file.write(_title, sizeof(_title));
            file.write(_author, sizeof(_author));
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_year), sizeof(int));*/
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(Book));
        }
        file.close();
        
    }

    void binaryFileRead(const std::string& fileName = "binaryLibrary.bin")
    {
        std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
            exit(2);
        }
        else {
            Book read;
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&read), sizeof(Book));
            std::cout << read._title << " " << read._author << " " << read._year <<  std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }


private:
    char* _title;
    char* _author;
    int _year{ 0 };
    int _titleLen{ 0 };
    int _authorLen{ 0 };
};

#endif
```

The problem is definitely in this part of code:

```
void binaryFileRead(const std::string& fileName = "binaryLibrary.bin")
    {
        std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
            exit(2);
        }
        else {
            Book read;
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&read), sizeof(Book));
            std::cout << read._title << " " << read._author << " " << read._year <<  std::endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
```

[image: Error in Visual Studio]

It even prints what I want to console app, but still doesn't return 0.

I don't know what's the problem, I tried a lot and nothing helped, I even thought that it can't be read from the `.bin` file to dynamic char or something.

By the way, my first protype didn't use dynamic array, I used constant size of array like `_title[50]` and `_author[50]` and it worked fine. I'd say perfect, but when I tried with dynamic arrays it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `Book` contains **pointers** to data stored elsewhere in memory. When you read/write a `Book` object the way you are, you are reading/writing those pointers as-is, not the data they are pointing at.  So, you need to handle that `char*` data separately.

Also, your `binaryFileRead()` is not even reading into the `Book` object that it is called on, it is reading into a separate temporary `Book` object.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void binaryFileWrite(const std::string &fileName = "binaryLibrary.bin")
{
    std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
        exit(1); // TODO: throw an exception instead...
    }
    binaryWrite(file);
}

void binaryWrite(std::ostream &out)
{
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_titleLen), sizeof(_titleLen));
    out.write(_title, _titleLen);

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_authorLen), sizeof(_authorLen));
    out.write(_author, _authorLen);

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_year), sizeof(_year));
}

void binaryFileRead(const std::string& fileName = "binaryLibrary.bin")
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Failed" << std::endl;
        exit(2); // TODO: throw an exception instead...
    }
    binaryRead(file);
}

void binaryRead(std::istream &in)
{
    int len;

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(_len));
    char *s = new char[len + 1];
    in.read(s, len);
    delete[] _title; _title = s;
   _titleLen = len;

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(_len));
    s = new char[len + 1];
    in.read(s, len);
    delete[] _author; _author = s;
   _authorLen = len;

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_year), sizeof(_year));
}
```

---

On a side note, there are other issues with your code:

- your default constructor is not initializing the `_titleLen` and `_authorLen` fields.  You really should consider using `std::string` for the `_title` and `_author` fields, instead of using `char*`+`int`. Especially since you are using `std::string` elsewhere in your code.
- your copy constructor is not copying the `_year` field.
- your `Book` class does not conform to the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it is missing a copy assignment operator.
- if you switch your `_title` and `_author` fields to `std::string`, you won't need to implement a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or destructor, as the default compiler-generated ones will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(Book));
```

`sizeof(Book)` calculates the size of the `Book` object. It is a ***compile-time constant value***. This means that you will always get the same results for `sizeof(Book)`. Your `Book` object contains two `char` pointers, and three `int`s. On a 64 bit platform this `Book` object should be 40 bytes long, and `sizeof(Book)` will be 40, and the above `write` statement will always try to write exactly 40 characters to the file.

Always.

It doesn't matter if the two `char *` point to empty strings, or to the entire contents of the Harry Potter novels. You will always get 40 bytes written to the file, which will include a pair of raw memory addresses that those two `char *` happen to have. Writing raw pointer values to the file is, of course, completely meaningless and does not produce any useful results.

The same thing also goes when reading from the file as well.

You will need to reimplement the entire logic for reading or writing to the file in some other way. Perhaps write all integer values first, then the length of each string, in bytes, followed by each string. And when reading it back you will need to implement the opposite logic. You don't need to do it exactly like that, you are free to design whatever serialization/deserialization format (as it's called) that works for you, but you simply can't `read` and `write` an object with pointers, or non-trivial members and call it a day. Unfortunately, C++ is not that simple.

Comment: So the problem is in design I've chosen? and I don't quite understand how should I rework read and write logic. Thanks for you answer

Comment: Yes. Do you understand why reading and writing `sizeof(Book)` does not work? Do you understand that it's a ***compile time constant***, probably 40 on your computer, because your `Book` object is always 40 bytes long? If you understand that, and ***why***, then the solution should be obvious.

Comment: @Balora you may have been told that arrays and pointers are the same. They are not. Arrays contain data. Pointers tell you where to find data. When you write an array, you write the data in the array. When you write a pointer, you write where to find data, and that's not particularly useful.